# Powershell reroute output files of exe into directory

Tags: windows, powershell

We have an internal process set up in Powershell which runs an exe file internal.exe which creates a lot log files in an absolute path "C:\This\is\absolute" which contains all the log files of the past 30 days. "C:\This\is\absolute" contains also log files from other applications and while internal.exe runs and creates log files in "C:\This\is\absolute" another application might create a log file there as well.
Now we need to send the log files created by internal.exe and for this they have to be moved to another folder "C:\Move\here" after having been created.

The process is currently simply set up as

```
Start-Process -FilePath "internal.exe"
```

I was looking for something like

```
Get-Outputfiles (Start-Process -FilePath "internal.exe") | foreach {Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Move\here"}
```

but I found only ways to write output to files, e.g., via Out-File. Is there a way to get something like the Get-Outputfiles which lists the paths of output files from a process?

Comment: So you want to monitor which log files `internal.exe` is actually writing to, and then move those after `internal.exe` is done running?

Comment: Exactly, this is want I need.

Comment: Is there no _name pattern_ that you can use to identify the files of interest, or are the file names randomly generated?

Comment: unfortunately, they are random due to security reasons

Comment: Then, do the logs from internal.exe contain a clue that it was written by that executable? Perhaps some formatting pattern that distincts it from the output of other executables?